# append quotation marks to links in a file in python

Tags: python, append

## I need to append few quatations to the below data

```
10.10.10.10:8000
10.10.10.10:8001
```

## I used the command below

```
file_lines = ['"http":','"http://"'+,.join([' '])for x in f.readlines(),+',"']
```

## the output required is

```
“http”: “http://10.10.10.10:8000”,

“https”: “http://10.10.10.10:8001”,
```

Comment: How do you determine whether it is `http` or `https`?

Comment: I think this question needs a better explanation, What Is OP Trying TO SAY!?

Comment: the input is =  10.10.10.10:8000                                                                                 
 i need output as =  “http”: “http://10.10.10.10:8000”,

Comment: This is not a question. This is a statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:)

I don't know if this is what you need, but I coded something real quick.

But keep in mind:

- I have no idea how you check whether it's HTTP or HTTPs.
- Your "join" part doesn't make sense, since it will loop over the array of data and make a string like **"http://10.10.10.10:8000","http://10.10.10.11:8000",...** instead of interpreting the array's items as a new line everytime.

So I hope this helps:

```
lineList = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open("path_to_data.txt")]
outArr = []
for line in lineList:
    outArr.append('"http": ' + '"http://'+ line + '",')

for item in outArr:
    print(item)
```

I tested it with this data:

```
10.10.10.10:8000
10.10.10.11:8000
10.10.10.12:8000
10.10.10.13:8000
10.10.10.14:8000
10.10.10.15:8000
10.10.10.16:8000
10.10.10.17:8000
```

And this is my output:

```
"http": "http://10.10.10.10:8000",
"http": "http://10.10.10.11:8000",
"http": "http://10.10.10.12:8000",
"http": "http://10.10.10.13:8000",
"http": "http://10.10.10.14:8000",
"http": "http://10.10.10.15:8000",
"http": "http://10.10.10.16:8000",
"http": "http://10.10.10.17:8000",
```

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer! Have a nice day! :)